# Can Intellij IDEA exist in a Netbeans Shop?

Tags: java, ide, intellij-idea

All my other colleagues use Netbeans, but I have an opportunity to use IDEA.  Will we be able to work on the same Java EE projects together, or will we have issues with projects, checking in and out of SVN, etc?

We primarily develop EE and Spring MVC applications using Glassfish on our desktops, and commit to an SVN, although it is possible that I may have to load a coworker's entire projec.

Comment: Why wouldn't it? Do you have a more specific question?

Comment: Convince your colleagues to use a better IDE, problem solved ;)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You will have issues with sharing projects, because the project folder and structure for Netbeans and IDEA is different.

However, you can attempt to share your src folders with one another and update your codes with one another through SVN, though I wouldn't advise it for compatibility reasons because you won't be able to properly share libraries and use other team functionality available in NetBeans.

So it won't be a good idea to use a different IDE so you don't waste time debugging compatibility.

Also, its useful to note that IDEA uses its own custom libraries for certain functionalities, and also build projects in a different way from NetBeans, so projects that appear to work on IDEA may not work on NetBeans and vice versa.

Bottom line, don't waste your time using a different IDE from the rest.

Answer (score 5):

As long as you are using some standard, IDE-agnostic build tool like [maven](/questions/tagged/maven), I see no problems. I work on IntelliJ IDEA while my colleagues use Eclipse - no issues except different formatting rules or import order - all of this can be customized.

Subversion (or any other VCS) is the least of your problems. Even if the rest of your team pushes Netbeans project metadata files, IntelliJ will simply ignore them.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Maven as your build tool, then **yes** (and Eclipse too).

All three have tooling allowing them to work well with Maven projects.

If you are using "plain" Netbeans projects I do not think that IDEA can work with them.  If so, I suggest you lobby for the change.  Maven is one of the investments that pay well of.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to fly in the face of convention and be the only one on a different IDE? You'll waste time on issues that nobody else has, have formatting hiccups, struggle with pair programming etc.

As much as I like freedom of choice, the development environment within teams should be consistent.

Comment: Some IDE's have tools that others don't.  Diversity is a good thing.

Comment: A few years ago when I was more of an optimist I'd have probably agreed with you. Having witnessed the horrors of "diversity" in the computing workplace on large scale projects a number of times recently, my stance is now fairly totalitarian when assembling a team. Having people on random IDEs, VCS clients/merge tools and operating systems just leads to a massive car crash somewhere down the line on large projects.

Comment: different ide shouldn't matter, it doesn't where I work thanks to maven

Answer (score 0):

I thought build tools like ant, maven or gradle are de-facto standart of java ee industry. Purpose your teammates to use it.